# Benchmarks for choosing the right CPU

Tags: performance, hardware

Is there any reliable benchmark resource (website?) for choosing the right CPU for Blender? I found http://blenchmark.com/cpu-benchmarks, but they seem not reliable. For example, according to them, AMD's Ryzen 1700 is even faster than Intel Core i7 7820X, which seems unreal.

How do you choose the right CPU or get insights regarding Blender performance of different CPUs?

Comment: http://blenchmark.com/cpu-benchmarks

Comment: But I mentioned that in the description, saying that I find the benchmarks very hard to believe (that Ryzen 1700 would be faster that i7 7820X)...

Comment: He, sorry, I pasted bad link, here: https://us.rebusfarm.net/en/tempbench?view=benchmark ...not Blender but it does not matter imo cause this is the most used bench for CPU performace in 3D.

Comment: More cores and higher Ghz equals faster rendering. The L1/2/3 caches also play a part, the bigger the better, this can reduce the CPU to memory transfers. Also look at a CPU/MB combo that supports faster ram, using DDR4-3200 can get the data in/out of the CPU faster than DDR3-2400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several standard blend files provided by the Blender Foundtation for testing and benchmark purposes available at [Demo Files](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/). The BMW scene as become a common test scene for various purposes.

In recent years due to the popularity and it has become an informal benchmark tool used by hardware manufacturers to provide a common ground for comparison. This has the advantage of using real world computational needs rather than artificial benchmark tools created for the sole purpose of testing

As such the Blender foundation has started a new initiative to provide an [official reliable benchmarking tool](https://www.blender.org/news/introducing-blender-benchmark/) for testing purposes.

This has materialized as a website called [Blender Open Data](https://opendata.blender.org/) that aims to collect performance data for various hardware configurations.

As of November 2018 status is still in beta testing, so not much information is available at the moment.

[image]