# How to make performance test while render my scenes

Tags: rendering, performance

I want to do a performance test via scenes that I created.
Could you give me some tips or applications which will check performance in the blender? GPU, CPU, Memory usage?

Or maybe it's possible to pin to render process and get information about usage?
I have skills that give me the possibility to write some code in C++ and C#.

Comment: Blender already has a benchmark if you want to compare your hardware with others: https://opendata.blender.org/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123229/benchmarks-for-choosing-the-right-cpu/123232#123232

Comment: Open data give me the possibility to do a performance test via my scenario? (a scene which I created?)